# Error while altering table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, alter

I'm just trying to add 2 columns to customer table

```
alter table CUSTOMER ADD ( CUSTOMERNAME VARCHAR(255) NULL
, CUSTOMERDESC VARCHAR(30) NULL )
```

but I get the following error when I try to run the script,

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '('.

Can someone tell me what is the mistake that I'm doing. Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the brackets for an alter statement so remove them. ie:

```
alter table CUSTOMER ADD   CUSTOMERNAME VARCHAR(255) NULL,   
CUSTOMERDESC VARCHAR(30) NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any `(` before the column names - just use:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customer 
ADD CustomerName VARCHAR(255) NULL, CustomerDesc VARCHAR(30) NULL
```

Does that work?

Comment: it does work. I would accept KAJ solution as he has answered first, wish I could accept both.